# How does Debezium guarantee all events within a single topic 'totally-ordered'?

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium

As I read from Debezium's FAQs, it is said that:

> Most connectors will record all events for a single database table to a single topic. Additionally, all events within a topic are totally-ordered, meaning that the order of all of those events will be maintained.

[How are events for a database organized?](https://debezium.io/documentation/faq/#how_are_events_for_a_database_organized)

However, AFAIK Apache Kafka only has ordering guarantees within a single **partition**. So if I expect the events in a topic to be ordered, I have to set that topic having only one partition, which sacrifices the throughput of Kafka, otherwise with other mechanism. But I didn't see any explanation about this in Debezium's documentation.

My question is, how does Debezium implement the ordering guarantees within one **topic**? Or which module of the **source code** should I study to find out the detailed implementation of this feature?

Answer (score 1):

to quote the [answer here](https://groups.google.com/g/debezium/c/L0TOC-vkO8Y/m/2P0V6cljCAAJ):

> ... Kafka Connect’s producer will use the default partitioning logic that computes the partition using a consistent hash of the message key, which in Debezium’s case is a struct containing the affected row’s primary/unique key...

So if the concern is that the same row/document should not be read out of order, then the concern is ruled out because the PK will always send the the event to the same partition